# Computing whether a set of polynomials cuts out a homogeneous variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, computational-algebra

I have a set of multivariate polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$, and I want to compute whether they cut out a homogeneous variety. My first idea is to compute the radical of the ideal $I$ that they generate, and then check whether the homogeneous components of each generator of $\sqrt{I}$ are in $\sqrt{I}$. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

For context: I have 96 degree-3 polynomials in 16 variables. I'm not hopeful that Macaulay2 will compute $\sqrt{I}$ in any reasonable amount of time (it has been running for 24 hours already).

**Edit:** Thank you, KReiser for suggesting I check if $I$ itself is homogeneous by checking if homogeneous components of the generators are in $I$.

**Edit 2:** I have now verified in Macaulay2 that $I$ itself is not homogeneous, so I am left with the original question of how to efficiently compute whether $\sqrt{I}$ is homogeneous.

Here's some more information on my specific situation. Let's arrange the 16 variables into a $4 \times 4$ matrix

$$X=
\begin{bmatrix} A && B \\ C && D\end{bmatrix}.
$$

My polynomials are the $3 \times 3$ minors of $X$, the $3 \times 3$ minors of
$$
\begin{bmatrix} A^T && B^T \\ C^T && D^T\end{bmatrix}.
$$

and the $3 \times 3$ minors of

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \vec{A} && \vec{B} && \vec{C} && \vec{D}\end{bmatrix},
$$

where $\vec{A}$, etc. is the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ viewed as a $4 \times 1$ column vector. This gives $3*{4 \choose 3}^2=48$ polynomials (which generate a homogeneous radical ideal). The other 48 polynomials are the same, with $X$ replaced by

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0&&1&&1&&0\\1&&0&&0&&0\\1&&0&&0&&0\\0&&0&&0&&0\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix} A && B \\ C && D\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The ideal generated by these latter 48 polynomials (call it $J$) is certainly not homogeneous, but I'm not sure about $I$.

Comment: I don't have any helpful comments, but a quick point of terminology: by "homogeneous variety" you mean that you have homogeneous polynomials? The term here is "projective variety." A homogeneous variety is one like projective space or a Grassmannian, where the automorphism group acts transitively.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks. "Projective variety" doesn't seem quite right either, because technically I am looking at the affine variety generated by these polynomials, and want to know if it is the cone over a projective variety. The affine variety itself will not be projective.

Comment: If checking $\sqrt{I}$ is homogeneous is difficult, it might be easier to check that $I$ is homogeneous, which is equivalent to showing that all homogeneous parts of the generators of your ideal are in the ideal. Perhaps we could give you some specific advice about this if you can give some information about how your polynomials are defined.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for this idea. I have edited my post to include more information.